# how to change the background only of a part of a plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

say  I got this command :

```
plot(1:100);
```

is their a way to make the only the part between say : `50 : 60` having a yellow background ? 
thanks for any hint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`fill`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fill.html) function to create a yellow rectangle, either behind the plot lines or with some transparency.

Put this before the plots:

```
xrec = [0,1,1,0,0];
yrec = [0,0,1,1,0];
fill(xrec,yrec,'y');
```

Or do this afterward (this will shade the plot lines as well though):

```
fill(xrec,yrec,'y','FaceAlpha',0.2);
```

Comment: would please take a look here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28392902/fill-function-in-matlab