# fill function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'm having issues unterstanding the function `fill` in MATLAB , I have a PSD of a file the I want to change it background like :

```
[xPSD,f] = pwelch(x,hanning(4096),2048,4096*2 ,fs);
    plot(f,10*log10(xPSD));

x= f(100:150);
y= 10*log10(xPSD(100:150))
fill(x,y,'y')
```

the result is in the right direction but not what I need : 
[image]

I would like get the color tell x axis like : 
[image: made with MS paint]

is their a way to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A working solution is:

```
[xPSD,f] = pwelch(x,hanning(4096),2048,4096*2 ,fs);
plot(f,10*log10(xPSD));
hold on

x= f(100:150);
y= 10*log10(xPSD(100:150));

yMax = ylim;
yMax = yMax(2);
x = x'; % Use this line only in the case that the size(x, 1) > 1
X = [x fliplr(x)];
Y = [y' ones(1, length(y)) .* yMax];
fill(X, Y, 'y')
```

What you were missing is that `fill` method looks for an area to fill. In the above code the area is defined by pairs of points. That, for the first (i.e. lower part) of the area we have the `x` vector and the `y` points. The second area (i.e. the upper part) is defined by the reversed vector `x` (image your pencil to first starting drawing towards rights for the lower part and then for the upper going left) and the points of the upper limit of your axes.

Edit:

Minimal example with the handel data from MATLAB:

```
load handel;
x = y; % Just to be consistent with the OP
fs = Fs; % Just to be consistent with the OP

[xPSD,f] = pwelch(x,hanning(4096),2048,4096*2 ,fs);
plot(f,10*log10(xPSD));
hold on

x= f(100:150);
y= 10*log10(xPSD(100:150));

yMax = ylim;
yMax = yMax(2);
x = x'; % Use this line only in the case that the size(x, 1) > 1
X = [x fliplr(x)];
Y = [y' ones(1, length(y)) .* yMax];
fill(X, Y, 'y')
xlim([0 200]) % To focus on the result
```

The result is:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is always a way ;)
In your case, you simply need to add two points in `x` and `y` that go to the top boudary of the plot:

```
x = f(100:150);
y = 10*log10(xPSD(100:150))

% Add two points
Y = ylim;
x = [x(1) ; x(:) ; x(end)];
y = [Y(2) ; y(:) ; Y(2)];

% Display filled area
fill(x,y,'y')
```

Best,

Comment: thanks for answer but here is what I get
Error using horzcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.

Comment: OK, that's because I don't have your inputs so I had to guess if `x` and /or `y` are hor. or vert. vectors. I've just updated the answer with a more geenral solution that should fit all cases.